# Is the Umineko ED used elsewhere?

Tags: theme-song, umineko-when-they-cry

Recently, I have started watching *Umineko no naku koro ni* (*When the Seagulls Cry*) and I found the ending song [(YouTube link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fTcLMsAMD4) of this anime very familiar and similar to a song I have heard before in another anime. In particular, the part 0:40 - 1:00 sounds somewhat like something I've heard before.

Now my question is: did the same singer perform for any other anime, or are there singers who sang the same song as he did (specifically, the part of the song at 0:40 - 1:00)?

**Edit:** From the comments, I know the song is not used in any other anime known to date.

Comment: According to a search through ANN's encyclopedia (which lists the OP/ED songs, most of the time), the only appearance of "La Divina Tragedia" is Umineko.

Comment: @JonLin Okay with that answerd i will rephrase my question a bit

Comment: The [Japanese wiki page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_divina_tragedia_%E3%80%9C%E9%AD%94%E6%9B%B2%E3%80%9C) only lists Umineko's ED.

Comment: I know that is not the answer you were looking for, but I found the chorus "kind of" similar to a [song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHOFE718uZ0) of Shoujo Kakumei Utena :P

Comment: @AlterLagos kinda is alike but still not what i am looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ending theme song is titled [*La Divina Tragedia: Ma Kyoku*](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_divina_tragedia_%E3%80%9C%E9%AD%94%E6%9B%B2%E3%80%9C). It was recorded by [Jimang](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%98%E3%81%BE%E3%82%93%E3%81%90). The song [does not appear](http://anison.info/data/song/57961.html) in any other anime. From the looks of it, Jimang has not had any other song appear in any anime. But one of his other tracks, *Sakura POP*, has been used in the Korean MMORPG, [MapleStory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapleStory).